# UTF-8 encode in php - Eurosign missing

Tags: php, utf-8

I read in a iCal File from a external server via curl. However I use UTF-8 in my outputdocument therefore the german umlauts Ä,Ö.Ü etc don't work (This showed up instead: `�`).

I correctly assumed the iCal File uses a different charset, and found `utf8_encode($value)` to solve my problem partly.

All the `�`s are gone and the proper ä,ö,ü chars are showing up. However I discovered,that a `€` Sign that was also displayed as `�` doesnt show up. But the `�` is also gone.

How do I get my `€`-sign back? ;)

Thanks

Comment: write it as HTML, eg `&#8364;` or `&euro;` ?

Comment: That would work, but I dont have control over what the users enter in the Calendar. Therefore I need a solution that converts € signs to UTF-8 afterwards. I suppose the iCal uses ISO 8859-1

Comment: have you tried `echo iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $value);` ?

Comment: The `utf8_encode` function assumes its input is encoded in ISO-8859-1. If your data is encoded in ISO-8859-1 it can't contain the € character; ISO-8859-1 does not include €. How is your data encoded?

Comment: Oh sorry its Windows 1252.

Comment: The Solution is: 
   

     iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8',$value);

Thank you guys ;)